# xsl cross references comparing one node with another

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I've an xml fragment such as below

```
<xml>
<person>
    <name>bob</name>
    <holidays>
        <visit>GB</visit>
        <visit>FR</visit>
    </holidays>
</person>
<person>
    <name>joe</name>
    <holidays>
        <visit>DE</visit>
        <visit>FR</visit>
    </holidays>
</person>


<countrylist>
    <country>GB</country>
    <country>FR</country>
    <country>DE</country>
    <country>US</country>
</countrylist>
</xml>
```

I'd like to list all countries from the countrylist with Yes or No depending on whether
 that person has visited the country or not. Thus an output for the above xml such as

```
Bob 
  GB Yes 
  FR Yes 
  DE No 
  US No

Joe 
  GB No 
  FR Yes 
  DE Yes 
  US No
```

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
<xsl:template match="xml">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="person">
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="person">
<xsl:value-of select="name"></xsl:value-of>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="holidays"></xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="holidays">
            <xsl:variable name="v" select="holidays"></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:for-each select="/xml/countrylist/country">
        <xsl:variable name="vcountry" select="."></xsl:variable>
        <xsl:if test="$v/holidays[$vcountry]">      
        <xsl:value-of select="$vcountry"></xsl:value-of><xsl:value-of select="'*'"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**edit**: I finally managed using the below; is there an easier way?

```
<xsl:template match="xml">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="person">
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="person">
    <xsl:variable name="hols" select="holidays"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="/xml/countrylist/country">
        <xsl:variable name="vcountry" select="."/>
        <xsl:if test="$hols[visit=$vcountry]">
            <xsl:value-of select="$vcountry"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="'*'"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to display the countries that each person visited (and not also display a "no" for the ones they *didn't* visit) then you don't need to involve the `countrylist` at all

```
<xsl:template match="person">
    <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="holidays/visit">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
        <xsl:text> *</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

If you do want the "no" entries then your approach is fine, but you could simplify it a bit:

```
<xsl:template match="person">
    <xsl:variable name="visits" select="holidays/visit"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
    <xsl:text> - </xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="/xml/countrylist/country">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test=". = $visits">
                <xsl:text>: Yes  </xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:text>: No  </xsl:text>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

taking advantage of the fact that an equals comparison between a node and a node set is true if the node on the left (the `country` in this case) has the same value as *any* of the nodes on the right (the `visit` elements of the current person).

Comment: Excellent...Thanks Ian.  That's a great tip!

Comment: @dmckinney the same extends to comparisons when you have a node set on both sides - the comparison succeeds if any node from the left hand set matches any node from the right hand one.  This is why `x != y` and `not(x = y)` can give different results - the first means "there is at least one pair of x and y that don't match" whereas the second means " there is _no_ pair of x and y that _does_ match".